# Why does my cursor jump across random lines in a specific PDF document and how do I stop it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, cursor

I'm trying to work with a PDF document that has a lot of tables and numbers. My ultimate goal is to get the data on it to Excel. Visually the document looks absolutely fine, but it appears that my cursor will randomly jump lines when selecting text. For example, if I place my cursor on the last character of a line in that table and hit the right arrow, it'll pop up somewhere at the end of the page, skipping a line, on the other side of the table, etc. This is making the information very difficult to copy/paste, much less put in Excel. Anyone have any tips to stop this from happening or other ideas? Thanks.

Thanks for the alt suggestion; it does make selecting in the PDF a lot easier. The only problem is when I go to paste whatever selection I made, it's all out of order. Any possible solution for that or is this basically beyond repair?

Answer (score 2):

Because the order that things are rendered or laid out in does not immediately translate to how you intuitively "see" the data.

If you are attempting to copy into Excel and are using Adobe Reader you might get better results holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while selecting the text. This does a "marquee select" rather than selecting things in the order the page "looks". [Adobe Keyboard Shortcuts](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop-elements/using/keys-selecting-moving-objects.html)

When copying tables I use this method to copy one column at a time. It's a bit more manual than copying all at once but, lacking the full Adobe Acrobat tool, the results come out far better, especially with tables where layout ends up going odd.